# How can I make IntelliJ refactor->rename parameter only rename the local version of it? (Kotlin)

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, kotlin, rename

I have an overridden function, where the parameter has a different name in the overridden version.

Original function:

```
fun hookEvent(event: Event) { ... }
```

overridden function:

```
fun hookEvent(e: Event) { ... }
```

This gives me a warning that it can cause problems when using named arguments.

When I select Refactor->Rename, and try to rename 'e' (in the overridden function) to 'event', IntelliJ searches my entire project and finds every single place where I have overridden the original function, and tries to rename the parameter in all of them.  Then I get conflicts because in some of those places, 'event' is already a local variable in those functions.

I only want it to rename that particular instance of the parameter, in that particular overridden function.  How?

Comment: Why don't you just rename the hookEvent function parameter yourself rather than using Intellij Refactor seeing that it is giving you problems.

Comment: You mean go in and manually change the parameter inside the function everywhere it's used?  Sure, I'll go do it in Emacs.  But IntelliJ's behavior doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @user3562927 I would also like the answer this this. Seenms random whether I'll get the quick edit or the buggy "deep edit".